# Javascript in Email

Tags: javascript, webmail

How can I send an HTML email with JavaScript from Gmail or Yahoo! Mail, to Gmail or Yahoo! Mail?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You shouldn't - allowing JavaScript to run in a e-mail client would be a **huge** security risk.

I originally said "you can't" but it's been pointed out that some clients will execute the Javascript. So, hopefully Gmail and Yahoomail don't allow scripting for this very reason.

On a personal note, I think HTML in e-mails should be avoided to. What's wrong with plain text?

Comment: Sadly, many HTML capable mail clients will execute the Javascript.

Comment: @Cry Havok - perhaps I should change the answer to "You shouldn't".

Comment: @Cry Havok name one.

Comment: @Pekka, older version of Outlook Express did ISTR (since they just hooked IE) and I've a feeling Outlook did too once.  Haven't checked recently whether that's still the case.

Comment: "What's wrong with plain text?" - The same thing that's wrong with plain text web pages.

Answer (score 1):

Send a link to a web page and request that they manually click the link.